# Infinite product of finitely-additive probability measures

Tags: pr.probability

I'm looking for a reference for the existence of a finitely-additive product probability measure for an arbitrary family of finitely-additive probability measures.  It's easy to prove, but I'd like to have a citation rather than to include a notationally messy proof.  If I was looking for the harder countably-additive version, I guess I'd cite [Kakutani](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-19/issue-3/Notes-on-infinite-product-measure-spaces-I/10.3792/pia/1195573633.full) (the result is credited in that case to Lomnicki-Ulam, but I've heard that they have a mistake in the proof).

Comment: On what sets should the product probability be defined?

Comment: And what should a product measure satisfy? Fubini's theorem does not hold for finitely additive probabilities.

Comment: I'd like the product probability to be defined on the field generated by products of subsets of the respective spaces almost all of which are improper, assigning to such a set the product of the respective measures of the proper subsets. That said, I am not sure I need an answer to the question any more. This came up in the context of probability measures on Boolean algebras, and I was going to move to the Stone spaces and use probability measures on them. But now I want to work directly with the Boolean algebras to avoid or minimize AC use.

Comment: Most proofs of the Daniell-Kolmogorov consistency theorem consist of two steps: Showing that a finitely additve measure on the field is induced. Using a regularity argument to show it is sigma-additive. So, there should be lots of proofs you could cite.

Comment: Right, but the proofs will generally assume that the measures we start with are sigma-additive. The first step of the proof won't actually use the sigma-additivity, and so I can cite the first step by saying "by the first step of the proof of the Ulam-Lomnicki/Daniell-Kolmogorov in [reference], which step assumes but does not actually use sigma-additivity". But that makes a nuisance for the referee--if I were the referee, I might feel obliged to go look up the reference to make sure sigma-additivity isn't used in the proof. Still, it may be moot as now I want to work with BAs directly.